# Android WebView, call c++ or Java functions from javascript and transfer objects

Tags: javascript, android, c++, webview

How to load and call c++ functions from javascript in Android WebView, which is using V8 engine since KitKat? Is there anyway to achieve this? I would like to hear some opinions about this approach. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I need to have communication between Java and Javascript specifically for the complex data types and objects. But the current Android WebView implementation allows only primitive data types and Strings, even not arrays. I thought maybe it is possible to somehow extend V8 implementation for Android WebView. It seems i-os UiWebView provides this feature with help of WebKit implementation, but Android doesn't. I am referring to the Apple documenation for 2 way communication between Obj-c and Javascript, which says:

- NSNumber objects will be converted to JavaScript numbers.
- NSString objects will be converted to JavaScript strings.
- NSArray objects will be mapped to special read-only arrays.
- NSNull will be converted to JavaScript’s null.
- All other objects will be wrapped by the WebKit into appropriate
  objects for the JavaScript environment.

For further details please refer to the following URLs:

[Using JavaScript From Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

[Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at cordova's implementation and add jni methods in your classes...

Comment: Does Cordova support this kind of feature?

Comment: you can call native function (java) that are bound to your C++ code. You cannot call c++ directly, as far as I know.

Comment: with Java I know, but the problem is that Java and JS communication is very restricted and provides only primitive types and String to transfer the data. I think V8 engine provides to make communication for the complex types, but it is not implemented yet. i-os UiWebView provides this feature with help of WebKit. I need the same for Android.

Comment: ok, do you mean you want to create built-in-kind-of-primitive-objects inside your webview's DOM ? if this is the point, I wish you good luck because that sounds really complex to me :)

Comment: @JuniusRendel I want to have possibility to transfer Java objects  to Javascript and vice versa. I need the same implementation which seems already exist in i-os, if I am not wrong. Please have a look at this documentation from Apple.


https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html


All other objects will be wrapped by the WebKit into appropriate objects for the JavaScript environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75715/discussion-between-junius-rendel-and-azat-martirosyan).